# Style all Elements of a div created via .createElement('div')

Tags: javascript, html, css, createelement

So I'm creating multiple new child divs inside another parent `div` with this code:

```
var parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent-div')
const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

So now I want to add an `onlick` event for every `div` I created, that resets the color for every other `div` inside the parent `div`, so that no multiple child divs are selected, and then set the color only for the clicked `div` to another color!

Any ideas?

Comment: Add a single onclick handler on parent and handle event.target

Comment: @Dragan good advice but, as a rule of thumbs, never use `event.target` without the `.closest()` method. Otherwise `target` might not represent what you expected to.

Comment: Just my curiosity: in the given example, where do I need to use closest?

Comment: @DraganS in the same place where you use `event.target`... Or in other words `event.target.closest(".some_selector")`

Comment: what about currentTarget? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: bl4ckshoxx - my advice to you - keep in mind that software development is not a religion - avoid to use dogmas. For example, if your requirement is to add an "Approve" button to your child divs and click on the button shouldn't change selection you shouldn't use closest. If you need to add an icon, then the selector closest is welcome :) In the given solution, you don't need closest. Also, let's say that you have margin around your items. Then you will be able to click the parent div, and click will add 'active' class to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent-div');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newDiv.className = "my-class";
  newDiv.innerText = `Foo${i}`;
  parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}
parentDiv.onclick = (event) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.my-class').forEach((el) => {
    el.className = "my-class";
  });
  event.target.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.my-class {
  color: red;
}

.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div"></div>
```

Comment: bl4ckshoxx - this is a lazy man solution. Small improvement might be to keep the active child div in a var (x) and replace loop in the click handler with x.className = 'my-class'; x = event.target; ...

Comment: But this onclick event gets triggered when i press the parent div. I want every child div i create to hold an onclick method which when executed resets the color of all div and set the color of the pressed div, so that only one div is colored. Dont know if u get what im saying :D i tried ur way but the color on the other divs dont reset

Comment: Added css for you - just click "Run code snippet" and click some item

Comment: This might be useful article to understand how the example does work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: In JS, avoid using `parentDiv.onclick`. There's the superior `Element.addEventListener()`. Also, don't use `className = ` Use `Element.classList` and its appropriate methods like `add()`, `remove()`, `toggle()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
        let parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent-div');
        for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

         let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
       newDiv.classList.add('see')

        parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
      }


      parentDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
       if (e.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
         e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
       }
     })
```

Comment: You should format the code with https://beautifier.io/ or something and add some comments to explain what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

Just to suggest a more robust and flexible way:

```js
// Utility functions
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL||document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, EL) => (EL||document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const ELNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// Now...

// Get element (Use an ID, not a class)
const EL_parent = EL('#parent');

// Function to toggle "is-active" class
const toggleActive = (EL_target, EL_parent) => {
  const EL_active = EL(".is-active", EL_parent);
  if (EL_active) EL_active.classList.remove("is-active");
  EL_target.classList.add("is-active");
};

// Function to create new child elements
const newChild = (content) => ELNew("div", {
  className: "child",
  innerHTML: content,
  onclick() {
    toggleActive(this, EL_parent);
  }  
});

// Create a couple of elements....
EL_parent.append(
  newChild("1 Lorem"),
  newChild("2 Ipsum"),
  newChild("3 Dolor"),
);
```

```css
.is-active {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent"></div>
```

So just a better way, and to avoid sloppy code like `className =`  or `Event.target` without the use of `.closest()`, as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is how you would want to do it for many reasons, but it might be beneficial for you to change the HTML value of the parent div. For example,

```
var parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent-div')
parentDiv.innerHTML = parentDiv.innerHTML + "<div class='{class name}'></div>";
```

Answer (score -1):

The approach proposed here is aware of which `div` was clicked the last time, changes its style accordingly and creates the `onclick` when the item is created.

```js
var parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent-div');
let lastDiv = undefined;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.style.width = "100px";
    newDiv.style.height = "100px";
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    newDiv.style.border = "1px solid white";
    newDiv.onclick = function() {
        if (lastDiv) lastDiv.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        lastDiv = newDiv;
    };
    parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div"></div>
```